# Store list of N number of most recent entries for a user in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to store a list of N number of recent entries, per user, and then persist that data in my asp.net application. Each entry is a List(of Guid, String).

To limit the number of entries, I think i need to create a class derived from List to be able to handle the limit, and remove the oldest entry from the list?

In session start, load the users list (if existing) from the data store into a session variable? on session end load list contents what is reaming back into the data store?

Is there any sort of persistence framework that will do some of the heavy lifting for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class derived from linked list as follows:

```
public class LimitedLinkedList<T> : LinkedList<T>
{
    public readonly int Limit;
    public LimitedLinkedList(int limit)
        : base()
    {
        Limit = limit;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        this.AddFirst(item);
        if (this.Count > Limit)
            this.RemoveLast();
    }
}
```

To test it you can make a test class that has Guid and String as you want

```
    public class Test
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

Then we can use our list class as follow

```
        LimitedLinkedList<Test> list = new LimitedLinkedList<Test>(2);
        list.Add(new Test() { UserId = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "MN1" });
        list.Add(new Test() { UserId = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "MN2" });
        list.Add(new Test() { UserId = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "MN3" });
        list.Add(new Test() { UserId = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "MN4" });

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            //Print item.UserName here
        }
```